# upgrading to windows 10 on sony vaio with nvidia geforce GT 330m card error with incompitability

Tags: windows-10, sony-vaio, nvidia-graphics-card

Does anyone have a way to work around windows 10 upgrade error message with nvidia geforce gt330m display compatibility on a sony vaio vpcz13ahx model?

Answer (score 1):

I found nvidia geforce gt 330m driver for windows 10 on following website.

[geforce gt 330m driver for windows 10](http://www.windows10drivers.com/nvidia-geforce-gt-330m-driver/)

Website claims that driver is developed by NVIDIA itself and available to public download on nvidia website.

Answer (score 0):

Start by following this guide:

[How to: A list of things to do if Windows 10 Setup fails](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-a-list-of-things-to-do-if-windows-10-setup/eba3c864-d9fe-4f8e-9468-81b1f89473ed)

Just because nVidia driver is the reported cause of failure, there could be other issues contributing as well.

Other things to try:

- Anything in the Event Log to help diagnose?
- Any issue with drives/space/crosslinked files (chkdsk)?
- Start with a clean Windows 10 installation - we know this is not always possible
- Clean up any and all old installations
- Uninstall as much as you can from applications and applications no longer used
- Be 100% sure you are clean of Malware/Spyware/Virii
- Clean up Temp/Temporary Internet/etc.  Use a tool like CCLeaner (stay away from the Registry cleaner part of it)
- Get the driver for nVidia from the OEM, first.  Then Microsoft.  Lastly from nVidia.

After you have surety you have cleaned up the system, restart it.  Then try the installation.

If it still has an error, what happens when you try "Safe Mode with Networking"?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  Tried most of them (except clean installation)  I will try safe mode with networking.  Scanning the internet, it seems to be the issue of the nvidia card and not being compatible with windows 10.  Problem is I can't even replace the card because I believe it is embedded in the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good video on this by Robot on YouTube. You need to do a regedit.

HKeyLocal Machine
Software
Microsoft
Windows
WindowsUpdate
OS upgrade folder

Right-click on black space
Dword 32bit Value

Allow OSUpgrade
Value = 1
Hexidecimal (y)

Close regedit
Go to Windows Update.

Watch the video. I can't find it now, but those were the steps.